# Reading a number of voltage samples with Fluke 8845A

Tags: voltage, multimeter, instrumentation

This question is for anyone familiar with Fluke's 884XA-series meters. I am looking to measure voltages with the Fluke 8845A meter. What I would like to do is measure a specified number of samples at a given rate. Here is what I am looking to do:

1. Measure 500 voltage samples.
2. Measure each sample at a 1ms interval.

I remember that last time I played around with the 8845A I specified the number of samples but could not get the meter to stop taking readings. So my questions are:

1. What is the appropriate SCPI command to specify 500 samples.
2. What is the appropriate SCPI command to measure at 1ms intervals?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Programming manual](http://assets.fluke.com/manuals/8845a___pmeng0200.pdf) of the Fluke 8845A (which I would suggest you read *before* you expect people to do things for you), you can do the following to optimize for speed (You should be able to modify this to achieve your required sampling setup (Hint: You can run more triggers and only one sample pr trigger)):

[image]

In addition to that, see the command table on pp.28-37, and specifically the following table:
[image]

According to the [User manual of Fluke 8845A](http://assets.fluke.com/manuals/884xa___umeng0000.pdf) (as WhatRoughBeast stated), these are the measurement rates:
[image]
Where do you get 995 S/s from?

Answer (score 0):

If you had Googled the 8845A user's manual, you would know that you can't run it at 1 kHz. See p. 1-22. In other words, RTFM before you ask a question.

Comment: I can do 995 measurements per second, that's close enough. Where are you getting that?